# Angular 2 - Override route with angular-route 3.3.0

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, router

I'm new with Angular 2. My app use 2 templates, one for guest and an other one for authenticated users.
To do that, I set this in the **app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
```

In my **app.routes.ts** file I defined outlets for authenticated users like that :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '' , component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' },
    { path: '' , component: LeftComponent, outlet: 'left' },
    { path: '' , component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
    ...
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

But for guest users, in my `LoginComponent` I want to replace outlets components by `EmptyComponent` like that :

```
{ path: '' , component: EmptyComponent, outlet: 'left' }
```

Routes are loaded in **app.module.ts** :

```
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ...
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LeftComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But I don't know how to do that. I tried with @Routes directive but I use angular-route-3.3.0 and this directive is removed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may [`resetConfig`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor) after you have logged In like below,

initiallly,

```
   { path: '' , component: EmptyComponent, outlet: 'footer' }
```

After Logged In,

```
this.router.resetConfig([
       { path: '', component: MainComponent },
       ...
       { path: '' , component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' } 
       ... 
    ]);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I import all urls in app.routes then I create a `user.component` which defines new routes and call `this.router.resetConfig` then Logged In components extends `user.component` but `resetConfig` has no effect (and no error in console)

Comment: i assume you are going to some login path first and then changing the routconfig if authenticated successfully, and then navigating back?

Comment: Oh, now I call `resetConfig` after login, before redirect the user. But now I have this error : `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
<router-out"): AppComponent@0:0`

Comment: Can you create a Plunker with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fix my problem.
Thanks @Madhu for your help.

1 - I import default routes (for guest) in my app.routes

2 - When user logged in I updates routes thanks to [Madhu Ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3508656/madhu-ranjan) answer

3 - Then I add the list of components used at point 2 in app.module.ts with key [entryComponents](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-when-entry-components)